# each() is always triggering twice for the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm implementing lazy loading functionality for images, which require an AJAX call to a REST backend.

I'm using the scroll and resize events of window to detect whether the image element comes into the viewport:

```
$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
          $('img[data-imageloaded=false]').each(function() {
              if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
                  alert($(this).parent().html());
                  //xhrLoadImage($(this).data("userid"), $(this));
              }
          })
      });
```

There are in total 16 images in the DOM with `data-imageloaded=false`, but I only scroll to one at a time to see the effect. In every case, the alert() is triggered twice for each element that enters the viewport.

Also using this to detect the visibility of the image element:

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top,
        elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight(),
        viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

I tried many things, but it keeps happening.

Comment: You're either running your `$(window).on` code twice, or two scroll events are firing, because scroll events fire constantly on scroll.

Comment: Try to see if the function "isInViewport" being called more than once and returns true

Comment: @ZivWeissman It is. On each scroll (or down key press), it's run twice.

Comment: hard to say, try to to make a working version in fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that scroll event is fired continuously during scroll event, and if you don't deal with that in your isInViewport function, it will run more than you expect.

Because I am not sure what is your structure of the imgs (do they take full height of viewPort?) if not then probably the condition is met more than once during scroll.

You can try one of the following:

- Use a "scrollStop" event like so:

  ```
  // Setup isScrolling variable
  var isScrolling;

  // Listen for scroll events
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function ( event ) {

    // Clear our timeout throughout the scroll
    window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );

    // Set a timeout to run after scrolling ends
    isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {

      // Your code goes here!
      console.log( 'Scrolling has stopped.' );

    }, 66);

  }, false);
  ```

Credit to code [here](https://gomakethings.com/detecting-when-a-visitor-has-stopped-scrolling-with-vanilla-javascript/)

What this code will do is simple- during scroll event, the interval will always get cleared, except the last time scroll event is fired.

- Handle "wasThisImageLoaded" of some sort in your function (its good only if you don't have too much images) - by a dictionary of bool where the key is your URL